error while downloading Tensorflow Object Detection
erorr:
AttributeError: module 'keras._tf_keras.keras.layers' has no attribute 'experimental'

This happened when I was trying to verify if I had correctly downloaded tensorflow object detection.
This is the code I use for the verification process:
VERIFICATION_SCRIPT = os.path.join(paths['APIMODEL_PATH'], 'research', 'object_detection', 'builders', 'model_builder_tf2_test.py')
# Verify Installation
!python {VERIFICATION_SCRIPT}

pip list shows me this:

absl-py                       1.4.0
asttokens                     2.4.1
astunparse                    1.6.3
bleach                        6.1.0
cachetools                    5.3.3
certifi                       2024.2.2
charset-normalizer            3.3.2
click                         8.1.7
colorama                      0.4.6
comm                          0.2.2
contourpy                     1.2.1
cycler                        0.12.1
Cython                        0.29.37
debugpy                       1.8.1
decorator                     5.1.1
dm-tree                       0.1.8
etils                         1.8.0
executing                     2.0.1
flatbuffers                   24.3.25
fonttools                     4.50.0
fsspec                        2024.3.1
gast                          0.5.4
gin-config                    0.5.0
google-api-core               2.18.0
google-api-python-client      2.124.0
google-auth                   2.29.0
google-auth-httplib2          0.2.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.63.0
grpcio                        1.62.1
h5py                          3.10.0
httplib2                      0.22.0
idna                          3.6
importlib_resources           6.4.0
ipykernel                     6.29.4
ipython                       8.23.0
jedi                          0.19.1
joblib                        1.3.2
jupyter_client                8.6.1
jupyter_core                  5.7.2
kaggle                        1.6.8
keras                         3.1.1
kiwisolver                    1.4.5
libclang                      18.1.1
lxml                          5.2.1
Markdown                      3.6
markdown-it-py                3.0.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.5
matplotlib                    3.8.3
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
mdurl                         0.1.2
ml-dtypes                     0.3.2
namex                         0.0.7
nest-asyncio                  1.6.0
numpy                         1.26.4
oauth2client                  4.1.3
opencv-python                 4.9.0.80
opencv-python-headless        4.9.0.80
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
optree                        0.11.0
packaging                     24.0
pandas                        2.2.1
parso                         0.8.3
pillow                        10.3.0
pip                           24.0
platformdirs                  4.2.0
portalocker                   2.8.2
promise                       2.3
prompt-toolkit                3.0.43
proto-plus                    1.23.0
protobuf                      3.20.3
psutil                        5.9.8
pure-eval                     0.2.2
py-cpuinfo                    9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.6.0
pyasn1_modules                0.4.0
pycocotools                   2.0.7
Pygments                      2.17.2
pyparsing                     3.1.2
python-dateutil               2.9.0.post0
python-slugify                8.0.4
pytz                          2024.1
pywin32                       306
PyYAML                        5.4.1
pyzmq                         25.1.2
regex                         2023.12.25
requests                      2.31.0
rich                          13.7.1
rsa                           4.9
sacrebleu                     2.4.1
scikit-learn                  1.4.1.post1
scipy                         1.13.0
sentencepiece                 0.2.0
seqeval                       1.2.2
setuptools                    65.5.0
six                           1.16.0
stack-data                    0.6.3
tabulate                      0.9.0
tensorboard                   2.16.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.2
tensorflow                    2.16.1
tensorflow-addons             0.22.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.9.4
tensorflow-hub                0.16.1
tensorflow-intel              2.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.14.0
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.8.0
termcolor                     2.4.0
text-unidecode                1.3
tf_keras                      2.16.0
tf-models-official            2.5.1
tf-slim                       1.1.0
threadpoolctl                 3.4.0
toml                          0.10.2
tornado                       6.4
tqdm                          4.66.2
traitlets                     5.14.2
typeguard                     2.13.3
typing_extensions             4.10.0
tzdata                        2024.1
uritemplate                   4.1.1
urllib3                       2.2.1
wcwidth                       0.2.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
Werkzeug                      3.0.2
wget                          3.2
wheel                         0.43.0
wrapt                         1.16.0
zipp                          3.18.1


where are you trying to install this

im using jupyter link to my computer

what os is your system

try install keras after the tensorflow

i have windows 10, python 3.11.7

i uninstall kerass then installed, itdidtn wokr

there is no way, i tried it one more time and it worked. Im in love with life.
Thanks so much unknown man

it worked because tensorflow reinstalls a different version of keras, so you have to install tensorflow then keras
